# Match empty parameter in URL with spark-java

Tags: spark-java

I am using Spark Java to match URLs with named parameters.

```
get("/hello/:title/:name/", (request, response) -> { return "Hello: " + request.params(":title") + "." + request.params(:name); })
```

This works as expected for e.g. **/hello/Dr/Mabuse/**.

I would like to allow not specifying the title component, i.e. accept **/hello//Friend/**. 
This path is not matched by SparkJava as the convertRouteToList function  specificially skips empty segments.
https://github.com/perwendel/spark/blob/master/src/main/java/spark/utils/SparkUtils.java#L38

*How can I achieve the needed functionality without duplicating path mappings (consider multiple optional fragments in the path)?*

I don't intend to start a discussion whether SparkJava is correct in swallowing the multiple slashes, as they might have had a very good reason to add that code there.
The double slash is properly discussed e.g. in https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8354/what-does-the-double-slash-mean-in-urls/8381#8381

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As empty segments are not an option, you will have to duplicate. But using Path Groups, it can be a minimal duplication. In your case, something like this:

```
path("/hello", () -> {
    String msg = "Hello ";
    get("/:name",        (req, res) -> msg + req.params("name"));
    get("/:title/:name", (req, res) -> msg + req.params("title") + "." + req.params("name"));
});
```

Not sure since what Spark version it's on, but for `2.5.5` it's working for sure.

You can read more about it [here](http://sparkjava.com/documentation.html#routes) (scroll down a bit).

Comment: As mentioned in the question I would like to avoid duplicating path parameters, moreover this is not extendable, e.g. for the case of the 3 parameters with the first and the last being optional. I will post a bug against spark-java as the loss of information is not justified.